# Alter the content overview page

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have created a Drupal 7 website where I want any (not just own) unpublished content to be editable for authenticated users. I wrote a module to change all the permissions so when I type the URL to edit the unpublished node with an authenticated user account it is editable.
The only thing I can't do is to display the unpublished node in the content overview page of the authenticated user.

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a View which lists all unpublished content by all authors.

You may also want to keep track of this issue: http://drupal.org/node/1192074 since the [View Unpublished](http://drupal.org/project/view_unpublished) module has the same problem you're experiencing.